# Format result after looping object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looping an object and expect the result as elements of a table

```js
var db = {
    "id": "8",
    "user_id": "24",
    "batchno": "367727",
    "ht_number": "jibhbu",
    "ht_taste": "uvyutvc",
    "pp_flavour": "ytv,yurtcrc,urt",
    "pp_fruit_batch": "cuyt,cytc,yt",
    "sl_flavour": "ouihyuigytvytc",
    "sl_appearance": "rtctr"
  },
  pp_ = '<table><tbody>';
for (var i in db) {
  if (db.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    var js = db[i].split(',');
    for (var x in js) {
      if (i.startsWith('pp_')) {
        pp_ += '<tr><td>' + i + ' ' + x + ' : ' + js[x] + '</td></tr>';
      }
    }
  }
}
pp_ += '</tbody></table>';
document.write(pp_);
```

I am splitting values that have commas so that each index of an array sits on 1 row (tr)

what I can't figure out is **how to place elements with the same index on the same level (row)** so I can I have something like

```css
table, td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> pp_flavour 0 - its value </td>
            <td> pp_fruit_batch 0 - its value </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> pp_flavour 1 - its value </td>
            <td> pp_fruit_batch 1 - its value </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> pp_flavour 2 - its value </td>
            <td> pp_fruit_batch 2 - its value </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> sl_favour 0 - its value </td>
            <td> sl_appearance 0 - its value </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> sl_favour 1 - its value </td>
            <td> sl_appearance 1 - its value </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and so on...

Comment: Please make the question more clear.

Comment: @Dasma tell me what you don't get so I can explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding each value of the table to a **2-D array** and than form the table from this 2-D array

**try below solution**

**NOTE**: this will also work with different number of rows and Column.

```js
var db = {
    "id": "8",
    "user_id": "24",
    "batchno": "367727",
    "ht_number": "jibhbu",
    "ht_taste": "uvyutvc",
    "pp_flavour": "ytv,yurtcrc,urt",
    "pp_fruit_batch": "cuyt,cytc,yt",
    "sl_flavour": "ouihyuigytvytc",
    "sl_appearance": "rtctr"
  };
function createTable(myKey){
var  rows = [];
for (var dbKey in db) {
  if (db.hasOwnProperty(dbKey)) {
    if (dbKey.startsWith(myKey)) {
      var values = db[dbKey].split(',');
      for (var val in values) {
        if (!rows[val])
          rows[val] = [];
        rows[val].push('<td>' + dbKey + ' ' + val + ' : ' + values[val] + '</td>');
      }
    }
  }
}

var myTable = '<table><tbody>';
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  myTable += "<tr>" + rows[i].join("") + "</tr>";
}
myTable += '</tbody></table>';
return myTable;
}
var ht_table = createTable("ht_");
document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML +="<br/>"+ ht_table;

var pp_table = createTable("pp_");
document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML +="<br/>"+ pp_table;

var sl_table = createTable("sl_");
document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML += "<br/>"+ sl_table;
```

```css
table, td {
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<p id="myTable">

</p>
```

Comment: could you explain, what do you mean by "each case"?

Comment: @Jonathan, updated code, added a function which will return a table string based on the key you pass

Comment: @Jonathan mark it as answer if this is what the solution you wanted :)

Comment: Check the rows variable, it stores a 2d array. Where each element of rows array stores cells of the row. All I do is join each cell to form a row and add that string to myTable

Comment: Just debug this code and use it as per your need,

Answer (score 2):

You could try indexing the database like this:

```js
var db = {
  "id": "8",
  "user_id": "24",
  "batchno": "367727",
  "ht_number": "jibhbu",
  "ht_taste": "uvyutvc",
  "pp_flavour": "ytv,yurtcrc,urt",
  "pp_fruit_batch": "cuyt,cytc,yt",
  "sl_flavour": "ouihyuigytvytc",
  "sl_appearance": "rtctr"
};

var prefixes = ["pp", "ht", "sl"];
var prefixedDb = {};
var result = "";

for (var i in db) {
  if (db.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    var parts = i.split("_");
    var prefix = parts[0];

    if (prefixes.indexOf(prefix) === -1) continue;
    if (prefixedDb[prefix] === undefined) {
      prefixedDb[prefix] = {};
    }

    prefixedDb[prefix][parts.slice(1).join("_")] = db[i];
  }
}

for (var k in prefixedDb) {
  if (prefixedDb.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    var db = prefixedDb[k];
    var dbIndexed = {};

    for (var i in db) {
      if (db.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        var vals = db[i].split(',');

        vals.forEach(function(val, j) {
          if (dbIndexed[j] === undefined) {
            dbIndexed[j] = {};
          }

          dbIndexed[j][i] = val;
        });
      }
    }

    result += "<table><tbody>";

    for (var i in dbIndexed) {
      if (dbIndexed.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        result += "<tr>";

        var indexVals = dbIndexed[i];
        for (var j in indexVals) {
          if (indexVals.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
            result += "<td>" + j + " " + i + " - " + indexVals[j] + "</td>";
          }
        }

        result += "</tr>";
      }
    }

    result += "</tbody></table>";
  }
}

document.write(result);
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Please note that this code may not be the most optimized code for this task.

Comment: Best to avoid using `for ... in` for arrays (`dbIndexed`).  A `for` loop or `forEach` would be better.

Comment: any way to use it in a table?

Comment: @GregDepoire-Ferrer thanks, looks good! Another question, now what if I want to have multiple if other than pp_? what if I want the ht_ and sl_ to use the same function?

Comment: @Jonathan I'm not sure if this is what you want but I edited the code to do this.

Comment: I want all pp_ to have their own table, ht_ their own, and so now

Comment: thanks for your help but @Nemani 's code is shorter and more compact

Answer (score 1):

Create a loop, incrementing a counter, which will determine if a key's split value should be output.

If there are no more values found at the index of the counter, stop looping.

```js
var db = {
    "id": "8",
    "user_id": "24",
    "batchno": "367727",
    "ht_number": "jibhbu",
    "ht_taste": "uvyutvc",
    "pp_flavour": "ytv,yurtcrc,urt",
    "pp_fruit_batch": "cuyt,cytc,yt",
    "sl_flavour": "ouihyuigytvytc",
    "sl_appearance": "rtctr"
  },
  s = '';

['pp_', 'ht_', 'sl_'].forEach(function(type) {
  var i,
      found = true;
  
  s += '<table>';
  
  for(i = 0 ; found ; i++) {
    s += '<tr>';
    found = false;
    Object.keys(db).forEach(function(key) {
      var js = db[key].split(',');
    
      if(js[i] && key.startsWith(type)) {
        found = true;
        s += '<td>' + key + ' ' + i + ' : ' + js[i] + '</td>';
      }
    });
    s += '</tr>';
  }
  s += '</table>';
});

document.write(s);
```

```css
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: how do I implement it on a table so each index 0 be on 1 row

Comment: Add the `<tr>` at the top of the loop.  See my edit.

Comment: thanks, looks good! Another question, now what if I want to have multiple if other than pp_? what if I want the ht_ and sl_ to use the same function?

Comment: I want pp_ to have their own table, ht_ to have their own table too, and so on

Comment: will keep this open until you get back to me :)

Comment: I see you have a good solution, but see my post for the answer to your questions.

Comment: yes, the chosen one allow me to place each case on its own table separately and wherever I need to independently

Answer (score 1):

You could take the wanted values out of the object, split them and take the max length for iterating the rows for the table. Then assemble the table by iterating the values.

```js
var db = { pp_flavour: "ytv,yurtcrc,urt", pp_fruit_batch: "cuyt,cytc,yt,42" },
    values = Object.keys(db).filter(k => k.startsWith('pp_')).map(k => (db[k] || '').split(',')),
    length = values.reduce((r, a) => Math.max(r, a.length), 0),
    table = document.createElement('table'),
    tr,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(tr);
    values.forEach(function (a) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i in a ? a[i] : ''));
        tr.appendChild(td);
    });
}

document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: this is the only solution that actually does what I need, but it's too advanced for me. I used a minified object for example purpose, how do I edit the code to add other cases (not only the pp_)

Comment: you could use an array of the wanted properties and replace this part `Object.keys(db).filter(k => k.startsWith('pp_'))` with it.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: you could use an empty string as default value before splitting, like `(db[k] || '').split(',')`